# trying to build MultiPart entity in java from a Objective-C text built multipart

Tags: java, android, ios, objective-c, multipart

I am converting someone else's iOS app into android, and I have ran into the issue of not being able to make heads or tails of this multipart entity they are creating.

```
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

    // file
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 90);

    NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: attachment; name=\"imagefile\"; filename=\"user_%@.jpg\"\r\n",userID] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


    // UserID
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userid\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:userID] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // close form
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

which I think looks something like this

```
---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449
Content-Disposition: attachment; 
name=\"imagefile\"; filename=\"user_" + userID +".jpg\"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
imagedata

---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449
Content-Disposition: form-data; 
name=\"userid\"

userID

---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449--
```

Now I am trying to rebuild this in java using MultiPartEntity

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();

HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(url);

        MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE, null, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

and am stuck on figuring the equivalent multipart for the text.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was this

```
     entity.addPart("imagefile", new ByteArrayBody(imageBytes, "image/jpeg", "user_" + userId + ".jpg"));
     entity.addPart("userid", new StringBody(userId));
```

so much more simple and easy, just had to try 30 different things to get it right.